# Pleasing google with their adsense format for doubleclick

Tags: google-adsense, folder, doubleclick-ad-exchange, advertising

I take a look here: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2594855?hl=en

and to maximize advertisements on my site, I want to fix rejected adsense requests. One thing google mentions is to create a doubleclick folder and put the file DARTIframe.html in it, but it doesn't anything more about the doubleclick folder.

Currently on my site, I have it set so if someone accesses just the doubleclick folder itself, a message is displayed to the users stating only authorized users have access and the return code is 200 because I only put in index.html containing the message.

My question then is, is my move OK for adsense, or should I remove that and simply allow them to see the folder contents (which contains only the DARTIframe.html file) and why?